# Random string generator using Java - Display and flash

Tags: java, string, random, generator

I was wondering if it is possible to display a random string on the screen in the same behaviour like a slideshow? Using just JAVA? I want to do it in Java if possible because my side project I'm working is in java.

I know how to generate random string using a textfile and display it line by line, the normal way. But I meant on a panel with black background and have the words to flash randomly?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with JavaFX or libgdx (there are lot of other possibilities)

Comment: This is entirely possible. It's not clear from your question, however, what part you are stuck on. Have you tried implementing anything?

Comment: I've never used those libraries before. I've been trying to find a guide to install javafx for mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MovingSlideShow {
    private static String[] data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        buildFrame();
        }
    });
    }

    private static void populateData() {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        data = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void buildFrame() {
    populateData();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("SlideShow");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    p.setLayout(null);

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Starting Text on Label");
    label.setLocation(200, 0);
    label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
    p.add(label);

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener(label));
        timer.start();

    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    private Random random;
        private JLabel label; 

        public TimerListener(JLabel label){
            this.label = label;
            random = new Random();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(data[random.nextInt(data.length)]);
            label.setLocation(random.nextInt(400), random.nextInt(400));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the code! This more or less what I want. But it is possible to make it more all over the place and random?

Comment: By move all over I suppose you mean moving the label randomly through the container. If so the updated answer may suit you.

Comment: Hey Syam, yes that's exactly what I meant. I was wondering I tried to use the array of text with reading a text file. In my text file I have a few sentences. Each sentence on one line. "This is line one" next sentence "This is line two".. etc. For some reasons, it doesn't appear on the text label. I just used the similar as this here - http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html

Comment: can you share the program?

Comment: Updated the program to read from a file. check populateData() method. If you are not particular about bufferedReader, then scanner is an easy option or if you are using JDK 7+ we have standard methods in File class to read to list. Hope this helps.

Comment: String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

Comment: I added that code into my program - just above the timerlistener is this the correct way?

Comment: What your method does is that it reads the content of the file to a single string and not to an array of string.

Comment: Hey, I tried to compile again with the updated code, and it works. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I was wondering if I could ask/email you a few questions related to the code above and a face/eye detection I'm working on? @SyamS

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to control the start of the slideshow with face detect for example? I have my own face detection up and running. But I was wondering if I could have a black screen and when the program detects a face, it starts the slideshow?

Comment: Yes that should be possible depending on how your face detection logic is. Say for example if you have a Java program that does this face detection then on successful face identification it may have a call back or send a boolean true or something similar. You could start the timer based on this.

Comment: I have a working face detection.Two classes, a frame and a panel that does all the detection.  A few methods that track face in the webcam capture/video capture. I have a boolean where I set to true in the method where it finds the face. so let's say if the total face is one / more, I set the boolean to true. I'm not how to connect that to the my slideshow class. I tried just creation new slideshow class but  ​​but that's just making the slideshow obj continuously all while the face/eye detector is running.

Comment: what I would the slideshow to connect to facedetector is that, I want to have keep track how many secs a person looking at the words(as a score), and possible store that data.

Comment: Look at the word? Does that mean you need to get the co-ordinates? What does your face detection algorithm do? You sounds like you are trying to use an eye tracking logic. If you could provide more details about the requirement please drop an email to dtaurus18@gmail.com